# Unconventional capitalisation becoming the norm

Tags: nouns, capitalization

Having now been involved in the writing of quite a few proposals as part of my job, I've noticed what seems to be a de facto convention: what I would consider common nouns or common noun expressions are capitalised.  My inference is that this is for emphasis, or to assign significance to the thing being referred to.

For example:

> ... any variation impacting cost will be raised with the Client via a
>   Project Change Request.

Has this now become accepted practice (in a de-facto sense, I presume)?  Is it "correct" English?

Comment: Nouns that are named for special reasons in business and legal documents are often capitalized. What you and I might call "small c" clients may become a "capital C" Client if  the usage is specific to a business practice specifically codified in a system of regulations or practices (especially in contracts).

Comment: Really, there's no such thing as "conventional capitalization". All you need to do is read anything from the 18th or 19th century to see the full flower of variation. Now that the internet's here, there are so many conventions you can't see the capital steps.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Actually, there is "conventional capitalization": *We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.*  Signed in convention September 17, 1787.

Comment: Client may have been defined earlier, as in "John Doe, hereafter the Client". This frees the writer to be able to use small c client in generic senses if they are very careful and very clear. This minimizes the amount of boilerplate that has to be personalized.

Comment: "Anytime you see that capitalized term elsewhere in the contract, it means the specific definition given to it in that contract, and not its generic meaning in normal parlance. If you see the same word in lower case, it has the normal dictionary meaning and not the defined capitalized meaning." [Link](https://www.owe.com/resources/legalities/11-contract-language/)

Comment: Capitalisation is a style issue. You can use a style guide and stick to it, or you can go by "feel." Ask for feedback from a supervisor for a while and then you're on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific example you gave, I find the capitalization of Process Change Request to be quite standard, because that is likely a specific, titled form/action used by the business in question. I think every job I've worked at in the US had between a couple and dozens of items like this--things like Team Performance Report. I personally find capitalizing "Client" to be unusual, but, like others have said, if that's standard in a particular field or a single company, then it is "correct" within that space.